# Re-initialize instance of class with new argument every time when argument is changed

Tags: swift, class, oop, parameters, initialization

How do I re-initialize / instantiate a model that takes one parameter every time that parameter changes its value? The model works, but with the old value of the parameter, but it needs to be reinitialized every time this parameter changes.

I found didSet and willSet, but i don't know how to use this correctly

```
var test = countDownPicker.countDownDuration {
        willSet {
            self.model.workTimeInterval = PomodoroModel.TimeInterval(newValue)
        }
    }
    
    self.model = PomodoroModel(workTimeInterval: PomodoroModel.TimeInterval(test))
```

PomodoroModel fields

```
public class PomodoroModel {

public typealias TimeInterval = UInt

weak var delegate: PomodoroModelDelegate?

var workTimeInterval: TimeInterval
let breakTimeInterval: TimeInterval
let restTimeInterval: TimeInterval
let numberOfCycles: TimeInterval

init(workTimeInterval: TimeInterval = 1500,
     breakTimeInterval: TimeInterval = 300,
     restTimeInterval: TimeInterval = 700,
     numberOfCycles: TimeInterval = 4) {
    self.workTimeInterval = workTimeInterval
    self.breakTimeInterval = breakTimeInterval
    self.restTimeInterval = restTimeInterval
    self.numberOfCycles = numberOfCycles
    self.state = StateNeutral()
    self.state.model = self
}
```

Comment: Code looks ok, everytime `test` receives a value, it propagates that value to the model. Maybe the problem is in `PomodoroModel`?

Comment: @Cristik  don't think so, my parameters are set by default.  If the code is correct, then the input parameter must change and used by the model as a new parameter

Comment: Then please show us how the model is using `workTimeInterval`. BTW, are you sure the `test` property is assigned with the expected values?